# Add plugin to a PlayN project

Tags: java, gwt, plugins, playn

Is it possible to display a HTML page in a PlayN game?

More generally, is it possible to add a plugin (native iOS code) to an iOS build of a PlayN project? (child browser, Accelerometer,..), same as the phonegap [plugins](https://github.com/rajpara11/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS) ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory yes. You have to define and create an API in playn and them you have to code the implementation for each platform.

The implementation in android should be easy, since you just use java for android, but for ios, you have to consider that playn uses `MonoTouch` to compile from java to native, I think they support `WebView` so you can go with it. Obviously the simplest implementation is the html5 one through gwt.

Comment: yes i figured that out, but still I'll need to recompile the playn jars ?

Comment: I mean there's no plug and play way to create (and share) plugins that can be added to the existing playn libraries.

Comment: You will not need to recompile playn jars. You can use your own java namespace for the playn core and implementation parts.

Comment: BTW: you could take a look to [tripleplay](https://github.com/threerings/tripleplay), an addon to the playn framework. Maybe if your html stuff is small you can use it to draw it, anyway you can use it as reference for your library.